# Issues with Django setup

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.4 and Django 1.8.

I can't seem to be able to start Django properly.  Whenever I run `django-admin.py startproject mysite`  it opens Sublime but it is missing the directories `manage.py` and all of the other `.py` files. `mysite` is just blank.

Any reason why? I have followed http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_start_project/README.html and so far had no problems until this.

EDIT: I fixed the problem, for some reason when I entered the command `django-admin.py` it would not work but when I removed the `.py` in the command it worked.

Comment: Python/Django versions?

Comment: Sorry, python 3.4 and Django 1.8

Answer (score 0):

To me this doesn't sound like a Django problem.  Since you do not mention with which OS you see this behaviour, I can only guess that you have an file type association that launches your code editor rather than the python executable.

For windows, anything ending in .py should be run by Python, not your editor.  Other OSes are more sophisticated about file names and their associations.